# How to test API with pytest

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I have the following [CRUD Flask application](https://github.com/sasadangelo/races/blob/main/app/races_api.py) where I have my CRUD api defined [in this file](https://github.com/sasadangelo/races/blob/main/app/races_api.py) for the Race objects.

I tested the API with some curl and they worked fine. Now I want to define a pytest to test them. I created the [following test file](https://github.com/sasadangelo/races/blob/main/test_races_api.py) but for all my tests I get:

```
E       assert 404 == 201
E        +  where 404 = <WrapperTestResponse streamed [404 NOT FOUND]>.status_code
```

I read docs, I browsed Internet but so far no luck.

**Can anyone help me to figure out what is the issue?**

Moreover, I would like to move my test_races_api.py file in the test folder but it doesn't work and always give me the error that the module app cannot be found (I tried ..app but another error appear).

**Can anyone help me also on this issue?**

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you put more information? The way you are importing the modules in the test file and the folder map would help.

Comment: Hi, I linked the file with code. Simply click on them you can check the code. The whole project is on github.

Comment: i am facing same issue